Move a GUI application to a remote DISPLAY
I have an app I start from the shell that starts a GUI instance (such as using gedit test.txt), which needs to run on a remote PC.
I want to be able to open the instance on my machine and be able to move it to the remote one, such that it will run with changes I made on it locally.
I tried to connect using ssh -X ..., start the app, and then disown it to try and catch it somehow on the remote machine (with a change of DISPLAY maybe), but when I exit the ssh connection, the local terminal is still "connected" to the process, and using ^C kills the app.
I tried using nohup as well but it didn't change the outcome.
How do I move the instance and catch it on the remote machine?

Seems that isn't directly possible, not without some work done in advance: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152291/70524

Basically, you can run a program on one machine and have it connect to the X server (i.e. have it display) on another (subject to permissions). The X mechanism itself doesn't allow for transfer of a connection from one X server to another. I'm guessing that xmove (mentioned in the referenced post) provides a sort of wrapper service that connects to the X server on the client's behalf, and allows reconnection. Doing what you want requires either something like that, or an ability within the program itself to switch between X servers.

@muru thank you, I believe Xpra is what I'm looking for, I will try it out
